# Inverter variável booleana react.js

Tags: javascript, react

```
onUpdateItem = i => {
    this.setState(state => {
        const subtarefa = state.subtarefa.map((item, j) => {
            if (j === i) {
                item.status = !item.status
                return item;
            } else {
                return item;
            }
        });

        return {
            subtarefa
        };
    });
    
};
```

Porque essa parte não funciona?

```
item.status = !item.status
```

Comment: Você poderia apresentar qual problema está acontecendo? Aparentemente, somente com o que foi fornecido o problema consiste na falta do caracter `;` no final da instrução.

Comment: não está invertendo o valor da variavel

Comment: @NatãLopes Você tem certeza que a execução está caindo nessa linha de código?

Comment: eu coloquei um console.log e não sei pq mas a função está sendo executada duas vezes nessa parte então no caso ele muda e dps retornar o valor

Comment: é tão dificil saber só olhando o código, mas, ai tem a condição que pode não está satisfazendo e a outra coisa também a variável pode não está realmente sendo alterada pelo fator imutável (talvez). Coloque todo o componente na pergunta !!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Olá, não funciona pq em react vc utiliza o conceito de ESTADOS para atualizar ou não os elementos da sua página.

Provavelmente, vc não vê o item atualizado pq nenhum estado mudou, logo não é novamente renderizado. A solução é vc criar um estado para controlar isso ou, colocar suas variáveis em um estado, lembrando que pode ser um objeto inteiro, array ou outros...

Para atualizar, você pode utilizar frameworks ou, manualmente, fazer todo o setState.

Recomendo: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29537299/react-how-to-update-state-item1-in-state-using-setstate

Basicamente copia seu estado, faz as modificações e atualiza seu estado.